# Measures on the space of projective measured foliations

Tags: reference-request, mapping-class-groups

I have questions about the action of the mapping class group $Mod(S_g)$ on the Thurston bounday $PMF$ that is given by the space of projective measured foliations.

1. Is this action an uniquely ergodic ?
2. Can you provide a concrete construction of a $Mod(S_g)$-invariant measure on $PMF$? If possible, please give me a reference about this construction.

I knew there is a measure called Thurston measure on the space of measured foliations, but it seems that this measure cannot down to $PMF$ to get a nice measure.

Thanks.

Comment: What people often study is a rather nice invariant measure *class* on PMF, where two measures are in the same measure class if and only if they have the same measure zero subsets. Namely the natural measure class obtained by projecting the invariane measure on MF. It's practically impossible to find a useful invariant measure in the sense you are asking, given that certain elements of this action, namely the pseudo-Anosov mapping classes, act with north-south dynamics.